# Python collections.Counter seems to break the original list

Tags: python, list, collections

Code:

```
sortedgroups = sorted(metagroups, key=lambda group: group[-1])
categories = map(operator.itemgetter(-1), sortedgroups)
categorycounts = collections.Counter(categories)

print('Writing output files')

with open('report.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for category in categories:
        f.write(category + '\n')
```

So this code works if I comment out:

```
categorycounts = collections.Counter(categories)
```

The for loop seems to break if I try to count the amounts of same strings in the categories list. Does `collections.Counter()` modify the original categories object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using Python 3.

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) now returns an iterator. `collections.Counter(categories)` exhausts the iterator, just like `list(m)` in the example below

```
In [3]: m = map(bool, [1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: list(m)
Out[4]: [True, True, True, True]

In [5]: list(m)
Out[5]: []
```

The solution is to build a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) before calling `collections.Counter`.
For example, a list can be constructed using either [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
categories = list(map(operator.itemgetter(-1), sortedgroups))
```

or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
categories = [x[-1] for x in sortedgroups]
```

Comment: So uhh, how can I fix this? I am very new to Python, but not to programming in general. Categories is a list like this before the collections.counter line: `categories = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']` Edit: Aha, seems like you already editer your answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping the map stuff in list() solves the problem.