# What is the intuition behind the below python code which uses itertools.chain and collection.Counter

Tags: python-3.x, collections, python-itertools

What is the intuition behind the below python code where an identical code giving two different outputs?

```
import itertools as it
import collections

# Chained list not getting printed
l1 = [x for x in range(10)]
l2 = [y*2 for y in range(10)]

l3 = it.chain(l1,l2)
l4 = collections.Counter(l3)
print(list(l3))
print(l4)

# Counter dict not getting printed
l1 = [x for x in range(10)]
l2 = [y*2 for y in range(10)]

l3 = it.chain(l1,l2)
print(list(l3))
l4 = collections.Counter(l3)
print(l4)
```

**Output**

```
[]
Counter({0: 2, 2: 2, 4: 2, 6: 2, 8: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 12: 1, 14: 1, 16: 1, 18: 1})

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
Counter()
```

**Update**

By converting the `itertools.chain` object to `list` explicitly, the outputs are same.

```
import itertools as it
import collections

l1 = [x for x in range(10)]
l2 = [y*2 for y in range(10)]


l3 = it.chain(l1,l2)

print(type(l3))
l5 = list(l3)
l4 = collections.Counter(l5)
print(l5)
print(l4)

l1 = [x for x in range(10)]
l2 = [y*2 for y in range(10)]

l3 = it.chain(l1,l2)
l5 = list(l3)
print(l5)
l4 = collections.Counter(l5)
print(l4)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
Counter({0: 2, 2: 2, 4: 2, 6: 2, 8: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 12: 1, 14: 1, 16: 1, 18: 1})
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
Counter({0: 2, 2: 2, 4: 2, 6: 2, 8: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 12: 1, 14: 1, 16: 1, 18: 1})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220180/python-collections-counter-seems-to-break-the-original-list

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the code is not identical. In the first example you pass l3 to Counter before you print l3. In  the second example you print l3 before passing it to Counter. So they are not identical so should not be assumed to be have the same behavior.

Next you need to understand is that l3 is an iterator. This means that it will allow iteration over its values but only once. I.E once you go thorugh all the values in l3 then l3 will be empty.

So in your first code example. You give l3 to Counter, it goes through all the values in it leaving l3 empty. so when you print l3 you do indeed get an empty list. Because counter ate all the values from l3.

In your second example you give l3 to print. So print eats all the values in l3 leaving it empty. you then pass the empty l3 to Counter which correctly counts nothing since you gave it l3 which is empty.

The key thing you should learn or look into here is that iterators can only be used once then they have nothing in them.

you can see this behaviour in simple form by making an iterator from your list and just calling print on it twice. you will see the first print eats all the values in the iterator so the second print prints the empty iterator.

```py
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
l3 = iter(my_list)
print(list(l3))
print(list(l3))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
```